# Django Model Latest Foreign Key Record

Tags: django, django-models

From a Django Model, how do I get a complete list of all these **snippets** a including only the latest **revision** foreign-key?

There could be a snippet with 5 revisions, but I only want the newest one to show.

```
# models.py
class Revision(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Snippet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    revision = models.ForeignKey(Revision)

# views.py
def a_view(request):
    Snippets.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
```

I can't see a way to say `.filter(revision__max=id)`. I actually don't know what to do because I think I might be laying out the model wrong when I think it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`latest()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest):

```
Snippets.objects.filter(user=request.user).latest('revision__created_at')
```

Comment: Or maybe ``latest('revision__updated_at')`` to get the snippet with most recent changes. Anyway very nice answer. Thumbs up!